# How to be more crafty?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I am trying crafting some potions, but the game says that I am not yet crafty enought to craft that craft.

Where I can see how crafty I am and how to become more crafty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your crafting skills are at the bottom right of your character page. To increase them, you must have selected them as one of your starting skill and pick it at level up.

Comment: So if I haven't choose a craft skill at character creation there is no way to craft anything?

Comment: Well, you can only craft level 0 items (cook food, make bolts, smelt ore), and at a very low efficiency. Otherwise, yes, you are stuck.

Comment: That's kind of a poor mechanic, to be fair..you should be able to learn in some way.

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck As a [Roguelike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roguelike), you learn by dying and re-rolling your character.

Comment: @Mark Trapp Yes, I know..but not being able to do a LOT for not picking a skill is a little silly.

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck One doesn't play Roguelikes because they're forgiving. There's a challenge to be had by choosing a set of skills that prevents you from crafting. If you happen to choose poorly the first time and wanted a build that has crafting, don't worry: you'll be dying soon anyway.

Comment: Can you increase crafting skills with items?

Comment: @Drake possibly, maybe Krong will enchant an item with a crafting buff, or you might find one. I haven't seen any in my travels though, if there are items that buff it, then they're painfully rare

Comment: @Jupotter Crafting skills are on the bottom *right*.

Answer (score 7):

If you have not chosen a craft skill that you can advance, the options are rather limited.

Craft skills can be buffed. You just have to be lucky enough to find an item with the buff. For example, Tinkerer's Goggles.

[image: Tinkerer's Goggles]

Note that this will increase the skill level. It won't give the other assorted benefits of advancing the crafting level as part of a character level.

Comment: Never seen that item yet, I want it!

Comment: I don't think enchantments that buff crafting skills can be randomly found. I think they have to come as an innate item bonus, and I think the Tinkerer's Goggles is the *only* item in the game with that bonus.

Comment: @Oak - A recent addition - the "Potion of Alchemical Inspiration" also is a crafting bonus.  While it is still speculative, it appears that special crafting item boosters akin to this one are on their way (a number of recipes that are crafting level 6 and 7, while one can only get to 5 naturally).